# Do I have to recompile if I want to change `--prefix`?

Tags: software-installation, checkinstall

When installing emacs 24.5 by compiling its source, I run `./config --prefix=/usr` and then `make` and then `sudo checkinstall` which creates a deb package and installs the binary files to `/usr`.

Now I would like to change installation directory to be `/usr/local`. I wonder if I must do the steps all over again, including compiling? Or do you recommend me to do so?

Is the deb package bound to `/usr`? No way to change it to bind to `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you should recompile

Long answer:

You don't *have* to recompile after changing the prefix from `/usr` to `/usr/local` with `./configure`, but since emacs uses the prefix in pathnames embedded within the executable (such as `/usr/lib/emacs/24.5/i686-pc-linux-gnu` and `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/etc`; see `src/epaths.h`), some files that emacs reads at runtime will not be found, unless either

- you recompile emacs (recommended)
- before running emacs, you set and export environment variables such as `EMACSDATA`, `EMACSDOC`, and `EMACSPATH` to override the incorrect builtin pathnames.
- you make symlinks in various places in `/usr` to point to various places in `/usr/local` so that the incorrect builtin pathnames resolve to the new locations.

Running `checkinstall` to monitor the `make install` procedure and generate a `.deb` package comprised of all the installed files won't mitigate any of this; the emacs binary will still contain incorrect pathnames.